Can't adjust brightness Ubuntu
I installed Ubuntu on my laptop several weeks ago and I can't adjust the screen brightness. The typical bar to adjust it does not appear and the keyboard keys do not change the brightness. It's strange because if I start Windows on the same PC the brightness is normal and can be adjusted, but when I start Ubuntu the screen goes dark and I can't raise it. I have tried a thousand ways and followed many tutorials. Has something similar happened to anyone?
